# Unknown tag in sequence tagging with LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have tagged dataset with a,b,c tags and have to tag incoming sequences with a,b,c,others categories. It should categorize and tag known sequences or say i haven't seen it before.

I think i should customize my network to make tags independent. So sum of tags scores should not be 1 and each tag score is independent to others.

E.g.

```
sequence a : .95, 0.1, 0,01 
sequence b : .02, 0.87, 0.9
unknown : .2, .15, .12
```

So what setting should i change in my neural network:

```
model.add(LSTM(128, input_dim=128, input_length=10, unroll=True, implementation=0))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=[accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is `Dense(4,...)` instead of `Dense (3,...)`.

There is absolutely no dependency between the four outputs. It would sum 1 if the activation were softmax.